# React-Native + Redux passing ID to component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, components

I am new to react-native and recently implemented Redux in my app.
The App is for ordering food in Restaurants :)

This is a snippet of my **Restaurant-Details** Screen with cards, which are representing the different menus:

```
<View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                        {menus.map((item) => {
                            return (
                                <Card style={{width: '95%'}}>
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress ={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Products', { menuId: item.sk_id } ,{bestellung})}>
                                        <CardItem cardBody style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                            <Text style={styles.textdes}> {item.typ} </Text>
                                        </CardItem>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </Card>
                            )
                        })}
```

As you can see the onPress Function navigates to the Product Screen and passes a menuId! (Product Screen shows all the food of a specific menu)

This is my **Product.js**:

```
class Products extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        loading: 1
    };
}
componentDidMount = () => {

    this.props.fetchProducts();
    this.state.menuId;
}
addItemsToCart = (product) => {
    this.props.addToCart(product);
}
render() {
    const { products, navigation } = this.props
     const {params} = this.props.navigation.state;
      const menuId = params ? params.menuId : null;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Header style={styles.header}>
                <Left>
                    <Button transparent onPress={() => 
                     this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                        <Icon style={{ fontSize: 35, color: '#FFFFFF'}} 
                         active name="arrow-back" />
                    </Button>
                </Left>
                <Body>
                    <Title style={{ fontSize: 25}}>{menuId}</Title>
                </Body>
                <Right style={{position: 'absolute', right: 20}}>
                    <Cart navigation={navigation}/>
                </Right>
            </Header>
            <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="#383838" 
              translucent={false} />
            <View style={styles.bodyProducts}>
                <View>
                    <Text style={{color: 
                     '#000', fontSize: 50}}>{menuId}</Text>
                </View>
                <FlatList
                data={products}
                renderItem={({item}) => 
                   <Product item={item} addItemsToCart= 
                   {this.addItemsToCart} product={item}/>}
                keyExtractor ={(item) => item.id}
               />
            </View>

        </View>
    );
}
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
products: state.products.items

})

export default connect(mapStateToProps {addToCart,fetchProducts})(Products);
```

The **Product.js** fetches products from my **product.component.js**:

```
 class Product extends Component {
addToCart = () => {
    this.props.addItemsToCart(this.props.item)
}



render() {
    const { product, menuId } = this.props;
    return (
        <Card>
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <Image source={product.picture} style={{width:400,height:150}}/>
            <View style={styles.productDes}>
                <CardItem cardBody style={{justifyContent: 'center', 
                   alignItems: 'center'}}>

                <Text style={styles.font}>{menuId}</Text>
                </CardItem>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 20}}>€{(product.cost).toFixed(2)} 
                 </Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 16}}>{product.description}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.addToCart} style= 
                    {styles.addBtn}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Hinzufügen</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
                        </Card>

    );
}

}

export default Product;
```

**The question is now: How can I pass the menuId from product.js to 
product.component.js without naviagtion?**

I hope I could make clear, what my problem is and looking forward to your solutions and help :)

Comment: Is the menuId stored anywhere in state yet?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should better separate your React components - which are basically views - and your reducers / side-effect (data fetching...) components.

State is in Redux Store, Views only display what's in store.

If you don't want to pass `menuId` through navigation params, you can add it to your store state - basically you add a field in your reducer's state to save the currently selected `menuId`.

In your **Restaurant-Details** screen, when calling `onPress`, you dispatch an action with the `selectedMenuId` to your redux store.
Then in your **product** screen, you retrieve the `selectedMenuId` from your redux store.

To understand Redux architecture , I like this gif:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using Redux, why not store the menu ID you're currently viewing in your store?  When the user selects a menu item, dispatch an action to set the current menu ID.  Then use a selector to to get the menu ID in the component you need it.

I hope I haven't misunderstood your issue.